# PreviewKeyDown of checkbox in Multi Select ComboBox in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox, combobox

I use [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/563862/Multi-Select-ComboBox-in-WPF) article to create multi-select `ComboBox`.

I want to select/unselect the `CheckBox` inside each item when pressing the Space button.

I tried to add `PreviewKeyDown` for the `CheckBox` but the event doesn't get raised.

I also tried adding `PreviewKeyDown` in the `StackPanel` but then I can't get the selected item that it's `CheckBox` is currently checked.

Comment: Add PreviewKeyDown event to main window instead of CheckBox .

Comment: How to get selected item for checked checkbox?

Comment: if (sender is ComboBox  && ((ComboBox )sender ).IsDropDownOpen && (((ComboBox )sender ).Items[0] as CheckBox).IsChecked = true){....}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use `EventSetter`.

```
<ComboBox.Resources>
  <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
   <EventSetter Event="PreviewKeyDown" Handler="EventSetter_OnHandler" />
  </Style>
</ComboBox.Resources>
```

and in code behind.

```
private void EventSetter_OnHandler(object sender,KeyEventArgs e)
 {
 var item=((ComboBoxItem)sender).DataContext as Node;
 item.IsSelected=!item.IsSelected;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle KeyUp of the combobox and make sure that the dropdown is open.

Update:

```
<Grid>
    <ComboBox x:Name="cbo" KeyUp="ComboBox_KeyUp" Height="30" Width="200">
        <CheckBox Content="checkbox1"/>
        <CheckBox Content="checkbox2"/>
        <CheckBox Content="checkbox3"/>
        <CheckBox Content="checkbox4"/>
        <CheckBox Content="checkbox5"/>
    </ComboBox>
</Grid>
///////////////////////////
private void ComboBox_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (cbo.IsDropDownOpen)
        {
          // select first and second
         (cbo.Items[0] as CheckBox).IsChecked = true;
         (cbo.Items[1] as CheckBox).IsChecked = true;

        }
    }
```

Comment: combobox in open, i want to checked checkbox that in selected item in press space.

Comment: @ar.gorgin I have added some code to give you an idea.

Comment: I use Multi select combobox, I want to add event for items .